# Does Kara (Supergirl) have a way to contact Superman?

Tags: arrowverse, supergirl

In the *Supergirl* TV show, we see that Jimmy Olson has a watch to contact Superman.

[image: Jimmy Olson's Superman watch]

Does Kara Danvers (Supergirl) have a way to contact her cousin? We do see her IM Clark in one episode, but that's not really the more accessible form of contact that I'm thinking of, since that's only when they are both at their day jobs.

Comment: She can whistle.

Comment: @cde She can *super* whistle!

Comment: @cde Well, she doesn't seem to have Great Wall of China rebuilding vision.

Comment: @Thunderforge thats.... a real thing? TIL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfwHe0NqVvY

Answer (score 3):

Of course, she does. They have each others mobile numbers. They're cousins, remember? Lol. If you watched the show you would've seen that and also how they communicated through email often.

Comment: I recall IM, but don't recall their mobile numbers. Can you give any example of when this happened?

Comment: @Thunderforge He texts her (on her phone, not via IM) in episode 1x19, stating he's on his way to help... causing Cat to gleefully ask for first Supergirl's and then Superman's numbers....